# shell script to help install packages using yum

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, yum

I wrote the script below as i am trying to help users install the packages they need from a yum repository.

The usage of the script is `./script PACKAGE VERSION`,

```
#!/bin/sh

PAKAGENAME=${1}
VERSION=${2}

if [[ -z ${1} ]]; then
        echo "you should at least specify a component name"
        echo "Usage      : installrpm {COMPONENT} {VERSION}"
    elif [[ -z ${2} ]]; then
        echo "the latest version of the component will be installed"
        sudo yum install -y ${1}
    elif [[ ${1} == all ]]; then
        echo "All component will be installed in latest versions available"
        sudo yum remove -y PAKAGE1 
        sudo yum install -y PAKAGE1 --skip-broken
        sudo yum remove -y PAKAGE2 
        sudo yum install -y PAKAGE2 --skip-broken
    else
        sudo yum remove -y ${1}
        sudo yum install -y ${1}-${2}
fi
```

When i use the `./script packagename version` or `./script packagename` it workes but when i try to use `./script packagename all` i get the following error :

```
the latest deployed version of the component will be installed
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
No package all available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

It seams that the script starts looking for a package name `all` even when i'm specifying the packages on this condition.

How can i fix this error and i'll be grateful for any enhacements on the script.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem depends on the second `elif`. You're checking the first opt (`${1}`) if it is equal to `all` but in the command `./script packagename all` the opt `all` is the second argument. So, you can try modifying the script as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash

PAKAGENAME=${1}
VERSION=${2}

if [[ -z ${1} ]]; then
  echo "you should at least specify a component name"
  echo "Usage      : installrpm {COMPOSANT} {VERSION}"
elif [[ -z ${2} ]]; then
  echo "the latest version of the component will be installed"
  echo "$PAKAGENAME"
elif [[ ${2} == 'all' ]]; then
  echo "All component will be installed in latest versions available"
  echo "$VERSION"
else
  echo "else"
fi
```

Comment: same error it didn't work

Comment: I change a little bit the code to try it. With this changes it works.